# InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException in Rest api generated using Jhipster

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, gateway, jhipster-registry

Description:

I am trying to make some rest api using Jhipster and i did it properly.

I did:

- First setup Jhipster Registry.
- Then create rest application.
- in application i created one entity named as **car**.
- the setup gateway for application.
- in gateway configure the entity available in rest application.
- and its done and runs properly on browser.

I was referring this site to setup jhipster.

https://www.baeldung.com/jhipster-microservices

-Application and gateway setup properly.
-Run Properly.

Problem:

when trying to add new entry it gives me error like this.

Error:

> 2018-10-12 16:19:01.172 ERROR 2656 --- [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTrait    : Internal Server Error
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:240)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:223)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy193.save(Unknown Source)
>       at com.car.app.service.impl.CarServiceImpl.save(CarServiceImpl.java:46)
>       at com.car.app.service.impl.CarServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3e4474a2.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
>       at com.car.app.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
>       at com.car.app.service.impl.CarServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$27cb3725.save()
>       at com.car.app.web.rest.CarResource.createCar(CarResource.java:57)
>       at com.car.app.web.rest.CarResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ccb383f6.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
>       at com.car.app.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48)
>       at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
>       at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
>       at com.car.app.web.rest.CarResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5aa88b3.createCar()
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>       at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:111)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at com.car.app.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:38)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:64)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:336)
>       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
>       at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure$1.getNextValue(SequenceStructure.java:95)
>       at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.PooledOptimizer.generate(PooledOptimizer.java:73)
>       at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:452)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:783)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:768)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy191.persist(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:490)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:641)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
>       ... 171 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
>     Position: 17
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
>       ... 205 common frames omitted

Update 1:

Here it is.

```
<property name="now" value="now()" dbms="h2"/>
<property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>

<changeSet id="00000000000000" author="jhipster">
    <createSequence sequenceName="hibernate_sequence" startValue="1000" incrementBy="50"/>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: The article you linked does not mention which version of JHipster is used and it uses some deprecated commands (like `yo ...`). The important message from your stack trace is `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist` but it's difficult to say what went wrong here as we don't have enough details to reproduce quickly without going through all manual process. Recent version of JHipster lets you create all your apps from one single JDL file which makes it easier to share https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl

Comment: @GaëlMarziou i did not understand what the problem is. please can you explain.

Comment: hibernate_sequence does not exist in your service's database. You should check whether it is included in liquibase changelogs in a file named as `***initial_schema.xml`, there should be something like `<createSequence sequenceName="hibernate_sequence"`.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou i update question please check it

Comment: So liquibase changelog is correct, so maybe something went wrong during execution at app startup and you did not notice

Comment: @GaëlMarziou now its run properly but i did not change anything. how can it possible..??

Comment: No idea as we don't know why it failed in first place :(

Comment: OK @GaëlMarziou no issue. Update me if you got answer and i will also if i got right one.